# AWS Webhook (how to access the payload of a POST)

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, webhooks

I created a webhook in AWS with the API Gateway and Lambda function. It all works but one silly thing... When I POST to the webhook, where do I access the payload? Also, how to I redirect he payload to a local folder or S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

The `event` parameter (the first parameter) sent to the Lambda function will have an API Gateway Proxy event. One of the fields in that event is the `body`, which will be the payload (encoded to a string).

You can make an S3 API call to put the body of the payload in S3. Alternatively, you could have the data go directly to S3 by using a [pre-signed url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).